# Ideals of etale structure sheaves

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it known whether or not every sheaf of ideals of the etale structure sheaf of a Noetherian scheme is generated by finitely many of its sections?  Of course it is trivially true for some widely used special cases.  But is it known one way or the other, in this generality?

Comment: what is the etale structure sheaf?

Comment: The sheaf $U \mapsto \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ defined on étale opens $U \to X$.

Comment: Yes, though I would write $U\mapsto \mathscr{O}_U(U)$ to define it. 

Comment: OK guys, I'm being really really thick right now. What's the difference with the Zariski structure sheaf? Aren't the two categories (etale/zariski quasi-coherent modules) equivalent for schemes (via the forget morphism)?

Comment: But I need not only quasi-coherent (sheaves of) ideals.  I want to know this for all (sheaves of) ideals.

Comment: Isn't every sheaf of ideals quasi-coherent, if the scheme is noetherian (and thus every étale open also is) ?

Comment: No. I don't think so. Over the spectrum of the integers consider the ideal which is 0 over every open including (2) and is the unit ideal over every open which does not include (2).

Comment: More fully:  Does every sheaf of ideals $\mathscr{I}\subseteq  \mathscr{O}_{\mbox{et}X}$  of the etale structure sheaf of a Noetherian scheme have a finite set of local sections  such that every section is covered by a linear combination of restrictions of those? 
This reduces to:  For a Noetherian ring $R$ and  etale sheaf of ideals $\mathscr{I}$ on $R$ is there a faithfully flat etale ring extension $R\rightarrow S$ such that for every etale $S\rightarrow T$ every section in $\mathscr{I}(T)$ is a linear combination of restrictions of sections in $\mathscr{I}(S)$?


Comment: OK, got it. thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Colin McLarty. You are right about the ideal sheaves of course... sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must apologize for posting a false answer.  in writing up a proof i discovered a gap which grew to a counterexample.

In fact not every sheaf of ideals of an etale structure sheaf is finitely generated.  I have added a counterexample to the end of my ArXiv paper on cohomology in second order arithmetic arXiv:1207.0276v2.  Intuitively, an etale ideal can hold information about arbitrarily high degree extensions which is not reducible to information about any fixed degree so the ideal is not finitely generated.

The counterexample shows that given any non-zero element $x$ of an algebraically closed field $k$ a single etale sheaf of ideals on the punctuated line $k\0$ can pick one $2^n$-th root of $x$ for every $n$.  The example has $x=1$ but rescaling $k\0$ takes 1 to any other $a\neq 0$.